# Unexplained use of frame budget in Chrome timeline

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have a weird issue where there is an unexplained use of frame budget as detailed from the Chrome (Canary version 28) timeline tools as seen below (I've also attached the raw log). There appears to be 56ms dedicated to an unknown use of CPU that can't be attributed to repainting, reflowing, recalculate styles, or JavaScript.

What could be potential causes for this?

[image]

Chrome timeline raw files: https://mega.co.nz/#!eQolEIxL!JYdx3UfV7qRR3zhRoS2NhRKt1jsXpPhzIsUJPu2nQYY

Comment: What does it have to do with Rails?

Comment: You're right, on second look this particular problem has nothing to do with Rails. I am, however, using Rails.